# Copy to clipboard script with breaks and more text

Tags: java, html

I am trying to make a fun script for work documentation. Here is what I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClipBoard() {
        window.clipboardData.setData('text',
                      document.getElementById('name').value +
                      document.getElementById('phone').value +
                      document.getElementById('serial').value +
                      document.getElementById('new').value +
                      document.getElementById('cuts').value +
                      document.getElementById('agts').value
                     );
    }

</script>
<form id="form1">
    Name: <input id="name" /><br />
    Phone Number: <input id="phone" maxlength="10" /><br />
    Serial Number: <input id="serial" maxlength="10" /><br />
    New/Existing: <input id="new" /><br />
    CU TS: <input id="cuts" /><br />
    Agent TS: <input id="agts" /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="ClipBoard()" value="Copy"/>
    <input type="reset" />`
```

Right now after I paste the inputs do not have "breaks" instead, the copied text copies in a line. Ex: namephoneserialnew etc.
I would like:
Name
Phone
Serial
New
Etc. with breaks.

If at all possible.

Also, when copying the inputs, is there a way to copy the text before the input.
Ex: Name: (with input), Phone Number: (with input) etc.

Any suggestions will be very helpful; this is just a basic script nothing serious. Thanks everybody!

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Is the OP asking for a java tool to copy to clipboard? Wouldn't it be easier to use flash such as the one that bitly.com uses? Additionally is this java or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add '\r\n' after ctl value.

```
function ClipBoard() {
    window.clipboardData.setData('text',
                  document.getElementById('name').value + '\r\n' + 
                  document.getElementById('phone').value + '\r\n' + 
                  document.getElementById('serial').value + '\r\n' + 
                  document.getElementById('new').value + '\r\n' + 
                  document.getElementById('cuts').value + '\r\n' + 
                  document.getElementById('agts').value
                 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't generate line breaks this way. You may try adding `"<br>"` in the code and that might bring up the line breaks.

```
function ClipBoard() {
        window.clipboardData.setData('text',
                      document.getElementById('name').value + "<br>"
                      document.getElementById('phone').value + "<br>" 
                      document.getElementById('serial').value + "<br>"
                      document.getElementById('new').value + "<br>"
                      document.getElementById('cuts').value + "<br>"
                      document.getElementById('agts').value
                     );
    }
```

And if you want Labels before the values you can just put a string before them.

```
function ClipBoard() {
            window.clipboardData.setData('text',
                          "Name: " + document.getElementById('name').value + "<br>"
                          "Phone: " + document.getElementById('phone').value + "<br>" 
                          "Serial: " + document.getElementById('serial').value + "<br>"
                          "New: " + document.getElementById('new').value + "<br>"
                          "Cuts: " + document.getElementById('cuts').value + "<br>"
                          "Agts: " + document.getElementById('agts').value
                         );
        }
```

BTW, you forgot the ending  tag in the HTML.